# Where are autoconf macros defined?

Tags: autoconf

The standard ones, like AC_PROG_AWK. I looked in the docs, but couldn't find them.

Any help or link would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert when it comes to automake/autoconf. Yet, a bit of googling revealed this which seems to contain the macro sources: [autoconf.git/lib/autoconf](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf.git;a=tree;f=lib/autoconf;h=8778222c6858bde178598d2b10ba4a4a5c3b8109;hb=HEAD).

Answer (score 1):

Automake macros starts with `AM_`.  The `AC_` prefix in your example means Autoconf.  You should therefore look into the [Autoconf manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Particular-Programs).

Comment: My mistake. I was talking about Autoconf.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the autoconf macros are stored in `$prefix/share/autoconf` (where prefix is the prefix used to install autoconf.)  In particular, the definition of `AC_PROG_AWK` can be found in:

```
$(dirname $( which autoconf ))/../share/autoconf/autoconf/programs.m4
```

(This is valid for autoconf 2.65, and probably for many version preceding it.)